# How to set confidence intervals in "emmeans"

Tags: r, confidence-interval, emmeans

I am have been working with the emmeans package to create an estimated marginal means for my data at .95% confidence level. Although I cannot seem to change it to .99% confidence level. Any help would be much appreciated. Usually I would use the "levels=" function but it does not seem to exist for emmeans.

```
library(emmeans)

emmeans(AcidLevels1, specs=~MAScore,)
```

Best,
-Nathan

Comment: You'll likely want the `summary()` or `confint()` functions.  See [the vignette on confidence intervals and tests](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/confidence-intervals.html) for more specific info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`emmeans` provides method `confint.emmGrid` to recalculate confidence intervals, and (probably more importantly) also adjust for multiple hypothesis testing.

As you don't provide sample data, here is an example using the `warpbreaks` data.

```
library(emmeans)
lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
emm <- emmeans(lm, ~ wool | tension);
```

To recalculate confidence intervals at the 99% level (without correcting for multiple testing) do

```
confint(emm, adjust = "none", level = 0.99)
#tension = L:
# wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# A    44.55556 3.646761 48 34.77420 54.33691
# B    28.22222 3.646761 48 18.44086 38.00358
#
#tension = M:
# wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# A    24.00000 3.646761 48 14.21864 33.78136
# B    28.77778 3.646761 48 18.99642 38.55914
#
#tension = H:
# wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# A    24.55556 3.646761 48 14.77420 34.33691
# B    18.77778 3.646761 48  8.99642 28.55914
#
#Confidence level used: 0.99
```

To recalculate CIs at the 99% level *and* correct for multiple hypothesis testing using the Bonferroni correction you can do

```
confint(emm, adjust = "bonferroni", level = 0.99)
#tension = L:
# wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# A    44.55556 3.646761 48 33.82454 55.28657
# B    28.22222 3.646761 48 17.49120 38.95324
#
#tension = M:
# wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# A    24.00000 3.646761 48 13.26898 34.73102
# B    28.77778 3.646761 48 18.04676 39.50880
#
#tension = H:
# wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# A    24.55556 3.646761 48 13.82454 35.28657
# B    18.77778 3.646761 48  8.04676 29.50880
#
#Confidence level used: 0.99
#Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 2 estimates
```

Comment: The user could also have just added `level = 0.99` to the `emmeans()` call.